# Microwave burns related to power per photon?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

In wireless telecomunications we have multiple bandwidths being used nowadays: GSM 900Mhz and 1800Mhz, UMTS 2100Mhz, LTE 800Mhz, 1800Mhz and 2600Mhz, Wi-Fi 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz, (reffering to European standards) but then, we have a microwave oven which produces electromagnetic waves at a frequency of 2,450 MHz (more or less - according to wikipedia) and this waves are harmfull.
Taking into consideration that this frequency is just a little above UMTS2100 and under LTE2600, why are this waves harmfull and the ones from telecom not? Is it because behind any frequency there is a power associated to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radiation produced by a mobile phone does have the same heating effect ([dielectric heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating)) as a microwave oven. However, as you suspected, the difference is power.

Power is a measure of energy per unit time which, for a given frequency, equates to the number of photons per unit time (not 'power per photon', as your title says).

As listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm), microwave ovens typically produce $\sim 1$ kW radiation compared to $\sim 500$ mW for a mobile phone (that's a factor of 2,000). In fact, standing next to a microwave oven, you will receive more radiation through leakage than you do from holding a mobile phone to your head.

Comment: So physically since the frequency doesn't really matter what changes is the amplitude of the wave?

Comment: @PedroTairum If you think of light as a *classical wave* then the power is proportional to the square of the amplitude. But if you think of light as a *stream of photons* then power corresponds to the number of photons per second. The classical conception of 'amplitude' does not apply to the photon description.